# Copying subfolders and files, checking "last modified time"

Tags: powershell, backup

I have made a backup script that:

1. Reads source file paths and destination folder path from an XML file
2. Checks if source file and destination path exist (for each file)
3. Checks if source file (same name) exists in the target folder
4. Checks the last modified date of every source and destination file, if the file exists in the target folder
5. Copies source files to the target folder if the file does not already exist, or if the source file is newer than the existing file in the destination folder, otherwise does nothing

This only works on source files, if a source folder is specified in the XML file, only that folder will be copied, and none of its content.

I don't want to use `Copy-Item -Recurse` because I want to check the last modified date of every item, and if it fails the above conditions I don't want to copy it at all.

This brings me to `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to list everything, but I'm having trouble coming up with something that works for this example:

```
C:\powershell\test\ (XML specified source)
```

Underlying structure:

```
C:\powershell\test\xmltest2.xml
C:\powershell\test\test2\xmltest.xml
C:\powershell\test\test3\test4\xmltest3.xml
etc.
```

i.e. I want to check every file before copying it but if say a folder has not been modified but a file inside it should be copied it should still work, AND retain the same folder structure.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Yes. Drop the XML config and use [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

Comment: Right, I was afraid of that. Looking at this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx
would it be something:

robocopy C:\powershell\source C:\powershell\test /e /xo

Comment: For backup purposes I'd suggest `/e /zb /copyall /dcopy:t /sl`. Add `/xj` if you don't want to traverse junction points.

Answer (score 2):

As Ansgar Wiechers says, you are reinventing the wheel, RoboCopy will do it much more easily. RoboCopy can also copy the security permissions and the created/modified dates as well, which is great. Relevant RoboCopy discussion: https://superuser.com/a/445137/67909

Still, it's not as fun as writing it yourself, eh? I've come up with this:

```
# Assuming these two come from your XML config, somehow
$xmlSrc = "c:\users\test\Documents\test1"
$xmlDestPath = "c:\users\test\Documents\test2"

#==========
# Functions
#==========
function process-file ($item) {
    #$item should be a string, full path to a file
    #e.g. 'c:\users\test\Documents\file.txt'

    # Make the destination file full path
    $destItem = $item.ToLower().Replace($xmlSrc, $xmlDestPath)

    if (-not (Test-Path $destItem)) {  #File doesn't exist in destination

        #Is there a folder to put it in? If not, make one
        $destParentFolder = Split-Path $destItem -Parent
        if (-not (Test-Path $destParentFolder)) { mkdir $destParentFolder }

        # Copy file
        Copy-Item $item -Destination $destParentFolder -WhatIf

    } else {  #File does exist

        if ((Get-Item $item).LastAccessTimeUtc -gt (Get-Item $destItem).LastAccessTimeUtc) {

            #Source file is newer, copy it
            $destParentFolder = Split-Path $destItem -Parent
            Copy-Item $item -Destination $destParentFolder -Force -WhatIf
        }
    }
}

function process-directory($dir) {
    # Function mostly handles "copying" empty directories
    # Otherwise it's not really needed

    # Make the destination folder path
    $destDir = $dir.ToLower().Replace($xmlSrc, $xmlDestPath)

    # If that doesn't exist, make it
    if (-not (Test-Path $destDir)) { mkdir $destDir -whatif }
}

#==========
# Main code
#==========
if ((Get-Item $xmlSrc).PsIsContainer) {

    # You specified a folder
    Get-ChildItem $xmlSrc -Recurse | ForEach { 
        if ($_.PsIsContainer) {
            process-directory $_.FullName
        } else {
            process-file $_.FullName
        }
    }|Out-Null

} else {

    # You specified a file
    process-file $xmlSrc
}
```

NB. The copies are `-WhatIf` so it won't do anything drastic. And it has two immediate problems:

- It makes everything lowercase. Otherwise you have to match the case properly because .Replace() is case sensitive.

  - I used `.Replace()` because `-replace` treats the `\` in the file path as part of a regular expression and doesn't work. There's probably an escape-string commandlet to fix this, but I haven't looked for one.
- If you put `\` at the end of the $xmlSrc or $xmlDestPath it will fall over.